# Can't access the full array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method which calculates total distance covered by a particular member which returns as a double array, like so:

```
public double[] getTotalDistances(){
  double[] distance;
   distance = new double[3];


    for(Activity r: diary ){

        if(r instanceof Run){
           distance[0] += r.getDistance(); 
        }


      }
    for(Activity c: diary ){
        if(c instanceof Cycle){
           distance[1] += c.getDistance(); 
        }
    }

    for(Activity s: diary ){
        if(s instanceof Swim){
           distance[2] += s.getDistance(); 
        }
    }


    return distance;
}
```

now the objects (members) are stored in another array called members, like so:

```
 public boolean addMember(Member m){
    boolean result = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < members.length; i++){
            if(members[i] == null){


                members[i] = m;
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }


    return result; //this is returned to have an indication if the member was added successfully or not
}
```

now I need a method that would print out all of the total distances of the members, I have tried this:

```
public void displayDistances() {



        for(int i = 0; i < members[i].getTotalDistances().length; i++){
            System.out.println(members[i].getTotalDistances()[i]);
        }

}
```

however, this only prints the first element of the first member, then a 0, and gives a null pointer exception on top of it all. Any Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: for getTotalDistances you are only modifying the first cell in the array. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: no, i actually accidentally left out other 2, will edit my post to include them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple things here. First I refactored your getTotalDistances() method.

```
public double[] getTotalDistances(){
   double[] distance = new double[3];

   for(Activity activity: diary) {
      if (activity instanceof Run) {
         distance[0] += activity.getDistance(); 
      } else if (activity instanceof Cycle) {
         distance[1] += activity.getDistance();
      } else {
         distance[2] += activity.getDistance();
      }
   }
   return distance;
}
```

Then your displayDistances() should be changed to this:

```
public void displayDistances(){
   for(int i = 0; i < members.length; i++){
      double total = 0;
      double[] distances = members[i].getTotalDistances();
      for(int j = 0; j < ditances.length; j++){  
         total += distances[j];
      }
      System.out.println(total);
   }
}
```

This will print the total distance traveled by each member. Good luck!

Comment: Nice, this works but for some reason still gives a null pointer exception on the line double[] distances = members[i].getTotalDistances();

Comment: Then you need to make sure all Members have been initialized. Thats not covered in your addMember method. So maybe add another method to check your member array. You may consider using a List instead of an array.